# Cannot detect if window is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I'm currently working on counting the number of opened tabs on my application. but my problem is it seems that my script won't detect events onload. Here is my code.
I'm using HTML5 web storage and native js. I'm not using jQuery to understand more on native js.

```
(function(w) {
    function Tabz(win, key) {
        this.name = '';
        this.storageKey = key;
        if(win.name != '')
            this.name = win.name;
        else {
            var windowArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)) || [];
            this.name = "tabz_"+ windowArr.length; 
            win.name = this.name;
            windowArr.push(this.name);
            localStorage.setItem(this.storageKey, JSON.stringify(windowArr) );
        }
    }

    Tabz.prototype.getStorage = function() {
            return localStorage.getItem(this.storageKey);
    }

    Tabz.prototype.removeWindow = function() {
            //remove window function here
    }

    var newWindow = new Tabz(w, 'counter');
    window.load =  function() {
        var count = JSON.parse(newWindow.getStorage()).length;
        alert(count!); // this wont execute so that I can check the count.
    }

   })(window);
```

Comment: Probably because the load even occurs before your function executes. Since this whole thing execute on page load anyway, why not just remove "window.load =  function() {  }"  and put the alert count in the main function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is on this line:

```
window.load =  function() {
```

This will add a `load` property to the window, not add an event listener. I think you are looking for `onload`.

```
window.onload = function() {
```

Incidentally, using event properties is considered bad-practice. Using [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) would be better.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    //Do stuff...
});
```

Comment: thanks I should have use onload instead of load, now it's working.

Comment: @frenchie: That would only happen if he side-loads the script after everything else loads, which doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara you really know how this works. could you give me references on how to learn native js? I'm a php programmer for 3 years and slowly shifting to javascript and node. I'm really having a hard time because javascript is async while php isn't and im used to MVC structures and javascript is more on prototyping.

Comment: @AnthonyLloveras: I always [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) for documentation. It's been many years since I learning JavaScript, but [Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/) is also a good resource for learning.